# How to retrieve data from Oracle database and Show in Datagridview with Different Format

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am a beginner in develop software with oracle database and vb.net.
Here is a problem I faced during display the data from oracle into datagridview with different format.

In Oracle database:

```
LotNo|Type|Enable
-----------------

L00  |1   |1

L00  |2   |0

L00  |3   |1
```

To be show in datagridview:

```
LotNo|Type1|Type2|Type3
-----------------------

L00  |1    |0    |1
```

Please give some suggestion in order to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.lotno,
       b.enable AS type1,
       c.enable AS type2,
       d.enable AS type3
FROM lottypeinfo a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT lotno,
          ENABLE
   FROM lottypeinfo
   WHERE covertype = 3) b ON b.lotno=a.lotno
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT lotno,
          ENABLE
   FROM lottypeinfo
   WHERE covertype = 1) c ON c.lotno=a.lotno
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT lotno,
          ENABLE
   FROM lottypeinfo
   WHERE covertype = 2) d ON d.lotno=a.lotno
GROUP BY a.lotno,
         b.enable,
         c.enable,
         d.enable
ORDER BY a.lotno ASC;
```